# C++ recursion for connectivity graph

Tags: c++, recursion, graph, connectivity

I haven't implemented anything yet, but I was thinking of using recursion to identify all cells in a grid that are 'actively connected' to a given cell, i.e., cells that are 'active' and directly connected by virtue of sharing a face with the (active) cell in question or more distantly/indirectly connected by sharing a face with one of its (active) neighbors. The disconnections come about because some of the cells in the grid maybe deemed 'inactive' (by whatever definition). My idea/pseudo-code is as follows:

```
//Call function to traverse connections
traverse_connections(cell);

//Traverse function definition
bool traverse_connections(cell) {
  //Check if cell is inactive or traversed - base case
  if (current cell is inactive or traversed) {
     return true;
  }
  //-Mark cell then move on to its neighbors
  Mark cell as traversed and add it to the list of 'actively connected' cells;
  bool ok = true;
  for(neighbor_cell in neighbors of cell) {
     ok &= traverse_connections(neighbor_cell);
  }
  return ok;
}
```

I think this covers the base case, marks the cell, then moves on to do the same for its neighbors, its neighbors' neighbors, and so on. Does this look OK? Are there any obvious gaps I am missing? Would appreciate if anyone with expertise in graph connectivity and recursion can weigh in. I am also having trouble coming up with an iterative equivalent. Any ideas on that would be much appreciated too.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution will not work, because it mixes up the concepts of "traversed" and "active/connected". The two are orthogonal: for example, a cell may be inactive and traversed, or active and not traversed. The `if` statement at the top of your pseudocode returns `true` for both, which is incorrect.

You should keep a table that marks cells traversed separate from the table that marks cells active. You need to make sure that a cell is marked traversed before going into the recursive call, otherwise the solution may be too slow, or even run out of stack.

Finally, the solution does not need to be recursive: you can accomplish what you need by a straightforward [*Breadth-first search*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search), which can be done with a queue instead of recursion.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think I need to use BFS for a graph with cycle. Looked it up. Wasn't too hard actually.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are marking the cells at the moment will most likely cause you problems. For example if one of these cells you are marking has neighbouring cells which need to be traversed later then they may go untraversed.

If you look into the [A*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) (A-Star) algorithm it should give you a good idea of graph traversal. [UCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform-cost_search) (uniform cost search) is also another algorithm which uses graph traversal.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I did some research on this and like @dasblinkenlight mentioned, I think what I need is a BFS for a graph with cycles. Haven't looked at the A* approach though, so I can't comment on whether it would've worked or not.